# Devexpress angular validation callback checking duplicate values wrong

Tags: javascript, angular, devexpress

I am writing a validation callback method for checking the duplicates in devexpress grid component
ts file

```
    validationCallback(e: any) {  
        let isValid = true;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.abbreviation_array.length; i++) {
          if (this.abbreviation_array[i] === e.value && e.value !== undefined  ) {
            isValid = false;
            break;
          }
    
        }
        if (isValid === true ) {
          this.abbreviation_array.push(e.value);
          this.abbrev_flag = false;
         
        }
        else {
          this.abbrev_flag = true;
        }
        
        return isValid;
    
      }
```

html file

````
<dxi-column dataField="Abbreviation">
                <dxi-validation-rule type="custom" [reevaluate]= "false" [validationCallback]="validationCallback">
                </dxi-validation-rule>
            </dxi-column>```
But while coming to first element or any other previous element it puts flag to true as it is entered in array and validation_callback is evaluated everytime the cell is entered with value.
Please suggest how to solve this
````

Answer (score 0):

populate the abbreviation array on initializing the grid like so

```
let uniqueAbbrs = this.gridData.map((obj: any) =>  { return obj.Abbreviation; });
uniqueAbbrs = ages.filter((v: any, i: number) => { return uniqueAbbrs.indexOf(v) == i });
this.abbreviation_array = uniqueAbbrs;
```

Then change the validation to just check the array!

```
validationCallback(e: any) {  
    return e.value ? this.abbreviation_array.includes(e.value) : false;
}
```

Comment: @JyotiSinha I am not using row index anywhere, could you share a stackblitz with the issue replicated